# Augmented Rreality - How is a local coordinate system defined (Vuforia-Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, augmented-reality, vuforia, coordinate-systems

Systems like Vuforia detect a fiducial marker and assign to it a local coordinate system.

How is that coordinate system first defined and assigned to that marker ? So that for example if we put in Unity a 3D object next to the virtual marker (which has its own virtual and local coordinate system), it gets registered on the right spot in the RGB image without worrying about the camera's extrinsics (or do we ?) Is there some kind of an intrinsic coordinate system defined when the marker is created ? Excuse my confusion.

More precisely (and correct me if the question is wrong), **How is the virtual coordinate system is registered to the one in the physical world** (detected with the camera) ?

Comment: Vuforia "knows" by the perspective and size of the recognized target the 3D position relative to the camera. Unity knows the 3D position of the camera in its 3D world space => Vuforia can place the image target in Unity accordingly to the camera position etc. Any content attached is placed by Unity not Vufory

Comment: The missing part I had in my mind is : Vuforia knows where unity's camera is :c Thanks for the answer again !